# How can I run a piece of code only once in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to run a piece of code which sets a variable to true when the app is launched for the first time and then sets it to false so that it doesn't run again. In short, it should run only once in its lifetime. I have tried almost everything including `dispatch_once_t` but didn't work for me. I put my code in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` etc but didn't work.

Comment: Your specification is insufficient for me to answer, because by setting something to true and then false, you are setting it 1) twice and 2) it's true for a finite period, so two calls to get the value might return true.  Can you explain more about the technical effect you are actually trying to achieve?  i.e. 'it should run only once' (what's 'it'?)  For instance - a function which returns 1 only the first time?

Comment: @AlexBrown what I want to do is that I have a boolean variable which when set to true runs a piece of code. I want to set that variable to true only once when the app is launched for the first time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need is persistence between app launches. Fortunately, this exists and is provided with NSUserDefaults.

I would do something like the following in your app delegate didFinishLaunching method:

```
let hasLaunchedKey = "HasLaunched"
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let hasLaunched = defaults.bool(forKey: hasLaunchedKey)

if !hasLaunched {
    defaults.set(true, forKey: hasLaunchedKey)
}

// Use hasLaunched
```

The first time you run the app, the key will not be in the defaults database and will return false. Since it is false, we save the value of true in the defaults database, and each subsequent run you will get a value of true.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am pretty new to NSUserDefaults. So now where do i put my code or how can I access the hasLaunched variable in my View controller?

Comment: The easiest way is just to use the first three lines posted in the answer in your view controller where you need access to hasLaunched. You could also make hasLaunched a property of your app delegate class, but then you need to worry about getting a reference to the app delegate in all of your view controllers.